# Multi-layer perceptron (neural network) - what am i missing?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, neural-network, perceptron

I am trying to implement my own multi-layer perceptron, unfortunately i make some mistake i can't find. Link to full program is here (it is light, simple c# console application). I am learning from [this book](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Machine-Learning-Algorithmic-Perspective-Recognition/dp/1420067184) , the code I am trying rewrite from batch to sequential form is at [this github](https://github.com/alexsosn/MarslandMLAlgo/blob/master/Ch4/mlp.py).

Link to my my project [is here](https://github.com/bartekwojcik/MultiLayerPerceptron) (github). 
The perceptron itself [is here](https://github.com/bartekwojcik/MultiLayerPerceptron/blob/master/ConsoleApp3/MultiLayerPerceptron.cs).

My test inputs are Xor function, and function, or function and some random function with a little noise.

My questions are:

**1)**
Before I covered all my code with infinity checks (for double overflow) all my results (and weights) very quickly (100+ iterations) converged to some super high values and results became `NaN`. After adding checks i just got `double.MaxValue`. Interesting part is that if i run the same program about 5 times i will get correct results (depending on number of iterations). The only random variable there are weights that are initialized using random numbers (in range `-1/sqrt(n) < x < 1/sqrt(n)` where `n` is number of neurons in hidden layer). What might be the cause of this?

**2)**
I am training and validating on the same data set (because it does not matter now) and because it is sequential algorithm I am shuffling training inputs and targets INSIDE my class.

```
public void Train(int iterations, double eta)
{
    _lastHiddenUpdates = new double[_hiddenWeights.RowLength(), _hiddenWeights.ColumnLength() + 1];
    _lastOutputUpdates = new double[_outputWeights.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
        ShuffleRows(); // <---- ShuffleRows is a private method without any ref parameter!
        this._currentIteration = i;
        var result = ForwardPhase(_trainingInput);
        BackwardsPhase(result.OutputResult, result.HiddenValues, eta);
    }
}
```

This is inside the `MultiLayerPerceptron` class. The thing is that after training the original array `double[]` also is shuffled! array of doubles is struct and structs are passed by value, not by reference and original array is in `program.cs`. Why is it changed outside of scope? Am i missing something? Now i am just cloning target arrays.

**3)**

This is super ugly

```
var infinity = deltasHs[i, j];
if (double.IsNegativeInfinity(infinity))
{
    deltasHs[i, j] = double.MinValue;
}
else if (double.IsPositiveInfinity(infinity))
{
    deltasHs[i, j] = double.MaxValue;
}
```

How can I simply this?

Note: During writing this program i was not paying attention to performance, sometimes i loop many times through one array just to keep readability at reasonable level.
I also know that you should not train and validate on the same data set but that is not my goal here, i will be perfectly happy if my perceptron will learn the noise as well. I just want this stupid goose to work (and understand).

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for posting. You could significantly improve your formatting, as it is currently not very nice to read. Please use backticks ``` to format code. Also you can hide those ugly links behind some expressive words. Well formatted posts will find more people willing to invest time into answering them! Good luck with your question

Comment: will do, thanks for suggestions